# Jquery prev() dont work with input

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal

I can´t change the css with prev, where is my mistake? [Fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/z7hw8/20/)

Tanks for looking!

---

Css:

```
.i1 {
    float: right;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
label {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    width: 450px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

Html:

```
<label>Titel:<input class="i1" type="text" name="titel" value="" /></label>
<label>Vorname:<input class="i1" type="text" name="vorname" value="" /></label>
<label>Nachname:<input class="i1" type="text" name="nachname" value="" /></label>
```

Jquery:

```
  $("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).prev("label").css("border-bottom", "1px dotted #63aec4");
  });
```

Comment: you have not wrote you html correctly first you must close label tag before input. and then you must call prev not parent. because label is not parent of input. it is prev element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).parent("label").css("border-bottom", "1px dotted #63aec4");
```

Comment: no it is not. you have not problem in jquery you have only little problem in html. it will work only for your html(which is not correct). you have put input tag inside label. for this reason parent() works

Comment: AEMLoviji, yes then it works with prev. It was easier to get my css working when it is inside, an there is no validation error. Now i understand the differenz of parent and prev :)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you putted everything into the label tag...try change the html like this:

```
<label for="titel">Titel:</label><input tabindex="1" class="i1" type="text" name="titel" value="" />
<label for="vorname">Vorname:</label><input class="i1" type="text" name="vorname" value="" />
<label for="nachname">Nachname:</label><input class="i1" type="text" name="nachname" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

look here please
[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/z7hw8/27/)

**first you must close you label tag before adding input.**

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for the element *next to* your `<input>` - you're looking for it's *parent*.

```
$(this).parent('label')...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("label").css("border-bottom", "1px dotted #63aec4");
```